# How can I UNCOMPRESS an Content-Encoded: gzip from HTTP Response?

Tags: java, compression, gzip, resttemplate

I did it using this RestTemplate configuration on my Main class but I would like to know if there are other ways to do it without RestTemplate.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

        public class MyIntegration {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MyIntegration .class, args);
        }
        
          @Bean
            public RestTemplate restTemplate(final RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
                return builder.requestFactory(new ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier()).build();
            }
    }
```